# PHP Include relative path - clarification

Tags: php, path, include, relative-path

I have a PHP page on my site in a sub folder called Articles.
The page is article.php.

The article.php page requires a common php page called _head.php. This provides the header for the pages.

_head.php is located in the root directory.
The /Articles directory is a subdirectory within the root.

I've included this _head.php page in article.php this way:

```
<?php include("../_head.php"); ?>
```

And this works fine.

The problem, however, is that the image elements within _head.php are located in the 'images' subdirectory (also off the root) and are referenced relative to the _head.php being in the root, like this...

```
<img src="images/services.gif">
```

So if I use _head.php for files on the root, it works great and shows all the images correctly.  But when I include _head.php into a php file that is not in the root, but instead in a subdirectory like /Articles (/Articles/articles.php), the images do not show up.

Do I need to change the _head.php file in how it references the images or is there some code I'm supposed to include in articles.php when including _head.php that tells it how to use _head.php?

I'm concerned about using all absolute paths because if I have to move this site to another server this is going to cause me issues.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning what I follow not going to the hierarchical complexity,

For any PHP file that is being imported into another PHP file in root simple `include/require_once (<path>)`.

For any file below root accessing other file anywhere within the root I use `include/require_once (../<path>)`.

For accessing files which are outside the root, I use the absolute path of that file.

Working on few php files what I have seen using absolute path is the best thing in two ways, a) you are free from remembering the paths of different files and b) if you are using CDN or if your files are on different servers then this is very helpful. Anyways opinions may vary, this is my personal view/choice.

Comment: I'm concerned about using absolute paths in the event I need to move my site to a new host.